# How to debug svelte with Chrome/Firefox devtools

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, svelte

I'm trying to implement Svelte in some parts of my web but I can't debug it with chrome devtools.

I generate sourcemaps to see the source svelte component and it let me add breakpoints but when going next step, the debugger breaks and it jumps lines.

In the example the debugger is stopped in the first line of the click handler and it works perfect: can see variable value etc.

[image]

But, when clicking the "Next step" button to go to the *else* statement the debugger breaks.

[image]

As you can see, the debugger is stopped in the *]*, but it should be stopped in the line 9. That occurs also if you put another breakopoint in that line.

I know I can use `@debug` in template and `console.log`'s in javascript but debugger is more powerful.

Comment: I usually just use the compiled output; a bit more messy but you don't have to deal with source maps not working correctly.

Comment: Apparently source map is incorrect, probably a bug in Svelte or in devtools.

Comment: What about adding the statement   "debugger" (without quotes)
at line 6.
if your dev tools are open it will stop the code execution and u will see variables values

Comment: @H.B. That's a little bit weird, isn't it? xD

Comment: @wOxxOm that's what I thought.

Comment: @AbdelkaderKEBIR Tried! But same result that setting manually the breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I think is a bad sourcemap generator. I've tried a new project cloning this repo https://github.com/sveltejs/template and it works as expected. Maybe Vite is generating wrong sourcemaps for Svelte components.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you**

I'm not seeing any error for debugger.
As the value of `name` is `availableNames[0]` so its 'Christian'.

> As you can see, the debugger is stopped in the ], but it should be stopped in the line 9

Debugger shouldn't stop at the line 9 cause condition is met with line 6, so it will go inside that if block.

Comment: Thanks for answer but the name in the example was "Esteban" because was the second time I called the function. Sorry for misunderstanding.
Still I didn't think that the debugger should be stopped in the closing bracket. It should mark the starting point as you can see in this vanilla js example: https://imgur.com/a/gmgr24J

Answer (score 1):

I did a try locally. I see a normal behaviour as expected in your comment. Maybe you have an issue with the browser it self, not svelte

First click

[image]

Second click

[image]

Comment: How you configured your project? Did you use `npm init vite my-app -- --template svelte` to start the project? Thanks

Comment: it's a project created 1 year ago, so i think it's not the same method as yours. there is no vite in my environement